# How should I resolve a field with leading underscore in graphene?

Tags: graphql, graphene-python

I have a field `_id`

```
class Article(graphene.ObjectType):
    _id = graphene.Int()
    article_id = graphene.Int()

    def resolve__id(self, info):
        return self.article_id
```

This one does not work, it will interpret `_id` as `Id`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Graphene tries to convert all fields to camel case to maintain convention with JavaScript: http://docs.graphene-python.org/en/latest/types/schema/#auto-camelcase-field-names

This can be turned off at the schema level or you can explicitly override the name of a field with whatever you want:

```python
class Article(graphene.ObjectType):
    id = graphene.Int(name='_id')
```